# ANGULAR UNIVERSAL not able to render with Angularfire2

Tags: angular, angular2-universal

Dear Awesome helper community.

hereby my first question ever!!! and happy to share it with you.

I am developing my web app with angular2 and now I would like to refactor it to Angular Universal.

In my application I use Angularfire2 and within the Angularfire2 library there is following providers:

```
export var FIREBASE_PROVIDERS = [
  COMMON_PROVIDERS,
  {
    provide: AuthBackend,
    useFactory: _getAuthBackend,
    deps: [FirebaseApp]
  },
  {
    provide: WindowLocation,
    useFactory: _getWindowLocation
  }
]
```

the _getWindowLocation refer to the window.location and we all know with AngularUniversal "NEVER TOUCH THE DOM".

I only use angularfire2 after user interaction, I don´t need it for the server-side rendering part.

Now I understand that I have to perform a kind of DI swapping and following Patrick and Jeff ng-conf Video I am not able to swap some providers called inside the angularfire2 library.

Does someone have an implementation for this problem?. Or can someone share an example of DI swapping that I could learn from and applied to the angularfire2 problem???

Thanks very much in advance.

Javier